# What is the shortcut to access the menubar in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

In Windows, I can access the menubar using the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. How can I achieve the same effect in Mac OS X? Specifically I am using Mac OS X v10.6 (Snow Leopard).

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The *exact same* functionality doesn’t exist on Mac OS X. There's no concept of underlined characters in the menus for quick selection.

You can move keyboard focus to the menu bar by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. Configure the shortcut in *System Preferences*.

[image]

You can press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> and start typing any menu bar item label to select it from the *Help* menu entry. This helps tremendously with the menus of rather complex applications.

[image]

Comment: I suppose I will have to be happy with this, thanks for the quick answer though.

Comment: @apoorv020 Also, once you've popped a menu open, you can type the name of any item on the menu and it will become selected. You can also use the Keyboard Shortcuts panel that DB pictured above to assign your own shortcut keys to any menu item in any application. So if there's a command you use often that doesn't have a predefined keyboard shortcut, just define one yourself.

Comment: This answer was a big help to me. I did need to do one additional step: on my MacBook Pro (OS X 10.9.1) I had to go to the Keyboard tab in System Preferences > Keyboard, and toggle the check mark next to "Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys".

Comment: You should move the second part of your answer to the top (the one about `Cmd+?`). I nearly missed it, and it's very useful. As for the underlined characters in the menus, too bad. Another point where macOS is user-friendly for beginner users (who like to use the mouse), and not so much for superusers.

Answer (score 40):

I prefer to use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd>/<kbd>/</kbd>. This opens the Help menu, then you can easily navigate to your desired menu section with the left/right arrow keys.

Answer (score 2):

You could assign shortcuts for AppleScripts like:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell (process 1 where it is frontmost)
    click menu bar 1's menu bar item 3 -- File
end tell
```